# c# Streamreader variables are read once and used by more than one method

Tags: c#

I have a text file containing comma separated values: Country, Capital and Population. I have created a c# program to extract each line of text to string n, string c and int p.
I have to create three methods:

How do I construct the code so that the variables from the text file are accessible to all three methods and streamreader only reads the textfile once?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;


namespace CountryList
{
    public class countryList
    {
        public static string line;
        public static string name;
        public static string capital;
        public static int population;
        public static string filename = @"c:\countries.txt";
        public static int popQuery;
        public StreamReader sr;
        public static string n { get; set; }
        public static string c { get;  set; }
        public static int p { get;  set; }
        public static string a { get;  set; }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            countryList cl = new countryList();
            cl.findAll();
            cl.getString(a);
            Console.Read();
            cl.startsWith(a);

            //cl.lesserPopulation(popQuery);
            //cl.getString(a);
            //cl.capitalHas(a);
        }
        public void findAll()
        {
            //Pass the file path and file name to the StreamReader constructor
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);

            //Read the first line of text
            line = sr.ReadLine();

            //Continue to read until you reach end of file
            while (line != null)
            {
                var text = line.Split(',');
                string n = text[0];
                string c = text[1];
                int p = Convert.ToInt32(text[2]);
                country list = new country(n, c, p);
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }
            Console.Read();

        }




        public string getString(string a)
        {
            Console.Write("Type starting letter for country name query: ");
            string user = Console.ReadLine();
            a = user.ToUpper();
            Console.Write(a);
            return a;
        }

        bool startsWith(string a)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))

            while (line != null)
            {
                line = sr.ReadLine();

                foreach (string n in line.Split(','))
                {
                    if (n.StartsWith(a))
                    {
                        country nc = new country(n, c, p);
                        return true;
                    } 
                }

            }
            return false;
        }

        //bool lesserPopulation(int p)
        //{
        //    Console.Write("Type number for population query limit: ");
        //    string number = Console.ReadLine();
        //    int popQuery = Convert.ToInt32(number);

        //    if (popQuery > (p))
        //    {
        //        object country = new country(n, p);
        //        return true;
        //    }
        //    return false;
        //}

        //public bool capitalHas(string a)
        //{
        //    Console.Write("Type letters to search for capital: ");
        //    a = Console.ReadLine();
        //    //string letters = Convert.ToString(a);

        //    if (c.Contains(a))

        //    {
        //        object country = new country(n, c, p);
        //        return true;
        //    }
        //    return false;
        //}

        public class country
        {
            public country(string n)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Country Name: " + n);
            }

            public country(string n, string c)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Country Name: " + n + " Capital: " + c);
            }

            public country(string n, int p)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Country Name: " + n + " Population: " + p);
            }
            public country(string n, string c, int p)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Country Name: " + n + " Capital: " + c + " Population: " + p);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "they fail."  And that means....?

Comment: the code runs and nothing happens . . . the findAll() sucessfully writes each line of text to the screen as Country: (string n) Capital (string c) and Population: (int p) but the startsWith method does nothing - console window accepts user value and then closes.

Comment: What you are expected from this code to display?

Comment: you're not populating any countries. when you create country list = new country(n,c,p);, you're not actually storing that anywhere. getString doesn't seem to actually do anything, it just asks for user input, and then returns it (but nothing in your code reads what that value is).  And again, startsWith never returns any items it finds. Are you storing it somewhere else that you omitted?

Comment: It's not necessary to use indentation, pre and code formatting here. SImply properly format your code in your editor (preferably using spaces rather than tabs for indenting), then copy/paste it into your post here, select it, and hit Ctrl+K or use the `{}` toolbar button.

Comment: It is supposed to take the user value (string a) and write to the screen any countries starting with that string. I had this working as an if else statement in the main code block until I tried to separate it into a method that could be called.

Comment: Well there are no Console.WriteLine calls, so I assume that those were accidentally deleted during refactoring. Also you are calling new country, can you share what that class looks like?

Comment: `while (line != null)` is null. so it wont enter the loop.

Comment: Ok, so is your issue that after it displays the list of countries your console closes before displaying list of countries that start with a certain letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading through your country list just once and storing it inside your class

```
public class countryList
{
    public static string line;
    public static string name;
    public static string capital;
    public static int population;
    public static string filename = @"D:\countries.txt";
    public static int popQuery;
    public StreamReader sr;
    public static string a { get; set; }
    public static List<country> countries = new List<country>(); <- this bit here
```

and add an entry in every line you find in `findAll()`

```
 public void findAll()
        {
            //Pass the file path and file name to the StreamReader constructor
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);

            //Read the first line of text
            line = sr.ReadLine();

            //Continue to read until you reach end of file
            while (line != null)
            {
                var text = line.Split(',');
                string n = text[0];
                string c = text[1];
                int p = Convert.ToInt32(text[2]);
                countries.Add(new country(n, c, p));  //store each country
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

Next, the startsWith method can simply look for items in the list where the country matches the first name

```
void startsWith()
        {
            countries.Where(x => x.name.StartsWith(a)).ToList().ForEach(x => x.Print());
        }
```

For this to work I modified the country class to provide a print method and store its properties

```
public class country
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string capital { get; set; }
            public int population { get; set; }

            public country(string n, string c, int p)
            {
                name = n;
                capital = c;
                population = p;
                Console.WriteLine("Country Name: " + n + " Capital: " + c + " Population: " + p);
            }

            public void Print()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Country Name: " + name + " Capital: " + capital + " Population: " + population);
            }
        }
```

I also updated the getString() method like this

```
public string getString()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type starting letter for country name query: ");
            string user = Console.ReadLine();
            a = user.ToUpper();
            return a;
        }
```

You'll also need to modify your Main function to look like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            countryList cl = new countryList();
            cl.findAll();
            cl.getString();
            cl.startsWith();

            //cl.lesserPopulation(popQuery);
            //cl.getString(a);
            //cl.capitalHas(a);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: much better approach. one suggestion instead of converting input to upper `a = user.ToUpper();` you can try using case insensitive search. `x.name.StartsWith(a,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`. This way you can check even if the csv has lower case country. Reference: [String.StartsWith Method (String, StringComparison)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I agree. I wanted to minimize the number of changes and try to just answer the question. I would also get rid of the `a` variable and just have `getString()` call `startsWith(user)`, and then do your suggested comparison inside.

Comment: Thanks for all your help - I have made all the changes you have suggested and the code looks a lot cleaner now. It still doesn't work. No errors just closes console after taking user input.

Comment: Did you add a wait in your Main call? Try adding a Console.ReadLine(); as the last call. I updated the answer to show what my Main function looks like.

Comment: Thanks Kolichikov it worked! That was driving me crazy. Much appreciated.

Comment: best approach: always test your console applications from command line.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following. Comment in code.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
line = sr.ReadLine(); // add this
while (line != null) // otherwise it line is going to be null and wont enter the loop.
```

In `findAll` you exit the loop when `line == null` so when you use `startsWith` it is already null.

Comment: exactly!! and you exit the loop when `line == null`

Comment: it won't, because it is being properly handled at `while (line != null)`